# WooCommerce turn session data into a WC_Cart object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create an abandoned cart script for WooCommerce. For this i need to see what the content of peoples cart are, so i'm using the following query to get this data:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

This results into an array with the corresponding session data. However the annoying part is that this isn't an object where i can easily use the WC_Cart methods to get the exact data i need. Is there any way to convert this data easily into an WC_Cart (*or something else*) object?

I tried creating a new WC_Cart object and assigning the productdata 1 by 1. However this seems like an inefficient way to do this. I expect there is some sort of method or class i'm missing.

```
foreach ( $results as $session ) {
    // Check if the session data contains cart data
    if ( isset( $session['cart'] ) && is_array( $session['cart'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $session['cart'] as $item ) {
            // Add each item to the cart
            $product_id   = $item['product_id'];
            $quantity     = $item['quantity'];
            $variation_id = isset( $item['variation_id'] ) ? $item['variation_id'] : 0;

            // Use WooCommerce functions to add items to the cart
            $cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a customer abandoned cart from another user?